# WP archive.php does not work

Tags: php, css, wordpress, archive

I have problem with my page http://velvetart.net

When I want to see monthly archive (http://velvetart.net/2013/10/) design is totally upside-down :/ I thought, when archive.php file is missing, WP use for archive page index.php instead, but then, why is my archive messy? :(

I try to upload archive.php, date.php, category.php, taxonomy.php, author.php, tag.php (all these files were same as index.php), but still look the same way :/ Please, does anyone know what to do with that? Thank you very much

Comment: in template, rename the date class used in post date. because the date class is affected in archive page body tag.

Comment: In style.css, go to line no 321 and change `.date` to `#maincontainer .date`.

Comment: thank you very much for your help! :) you just solved my biggest problem! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occur because of `date` class used in body tag as well as inside body container( used in the post date).

Solution:

In style.css, go to line no 321 and change `.date` to `#maincontainer .date`